# How to ficJQuery CDN not loading in node.js app, preventing server from running

Tags: jquery, node.js, cdn

I have started what I thought would be a simple grocery list app. and down the line I plan on adding a feature to add some recipes, then pull the ingredients from recipes into the grocery list.

on my landing page i cannot get my jquery cdn to work

I've tried having the jquery cdn in the header, down at the bottom of my html, and tried all versions of jquery.

I have an index.js file for my overall app

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var path = require('path');

var listAni = require('./public/js/list.js');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('home');
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function() {
    console.log('Express server listening on port %d in %s mode', this.address().port, app.settings.env);
});
```

then my home.ejs for my landing page

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/main.css">


    <title>Groceries</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="container">
      <h1>List<i class="fa fa-plus"></i></h1>
      <input type="text" placeholder="add item">

      <ul>
        <li><span><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span>'apple'</li>
        <li><span><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span>'basil'</li>
        <li><span><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span>'almonds'</li>
        <li><span><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span>'milk'</li>
        <li><span><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span>'butter'</li>
      </ul>
    </div>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="/public/js/list.js" ></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and a list.js file to control the behavior of the landing

```
// Check Off Specific Todos By Clicking
$('ul').on('click', 'li', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('completed');
});

//Click on X to delete Todo
$('ul').on('click', 'span', function(event) {
    $(this).parent().fadeOut(500, function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });
    event.stopPropagation();
});

$("input[type='text']").keypress(function(event) {
    if (event.which === 13) {
        //grabbing new todo text from input
        var todoText = $(this).val();
        $(this).val('');
        //create a new li and add to ul
        $('ul').append("<li><span><i class='fa fa-trash'></i></span> " + todoText + '</li>');
    }
});

$('.fa-plus').click(function() {
    $("input[type='text']").fadeToggle();
});
```

I was thinking the JQuery commands would work, but it wont.

Comment: You're loading jQuery twice: once for `jquery.min.js` and one for `jquery.js`. Delete this one: `https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.9.0.js` since it's the older verision (unless you need backwards compatibility).

Comment: woops. i actually forgot to remove the new version when i tried to see if an older version works.

it still doesnt work with just one link

```